# C++ Calculator for complex numbers

Tags: c++, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, complex-numbers

I've written a little calculator in C++ for complex numbers:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ComplexNumber {

    public:
        double real;
        double imaginary;

        void add(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {

            //Just add real- and imaginary-parts
            double real = a.real + b.real;
            double imaginary = a.imaginary + b.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            cout << "a + b = " << c.real << " + (" << c.imaginary << ") * i" << endl; 
        }

        void sub(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {

            //Just subtract real- and imaginary-parts
            double real = a.real - b.real;
            double imaginary = a.imaginary - b.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            cout << "a - b = " << c.real << " + (" << c.imaginary << ") * i" << endl; 
        }

        void multiply(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {

            //Use binomial theorem to find formula to multiply complex numbers
            double real = a.real * b.real - a.imaginary * b.imaginary;
            double imaginary = a.imaginary * b.real + a.real * b.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            cout << "a * b = " << c.real << " + (" << c.imaginary << ") * i" << endl; 
        }


        void divide(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {

            //Again binomial theorem
            double real = (a.real * b.real + a.imaginary * b.imaginary) / (b.real * b.real + b.imaginary * b.imaginary);
            double imaginary = (a.imaginary * b.real - a.real * b.imaginary) / (b.real * b.real + b.imaginary * b.imaginary);
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            cout << "a : b = " << c.real << " + (" << c.imaginary << ") * i" << endl; 
        }

    /*
     * Constructor to create complex numbers
     */
    ComplexNumber(double real, double imaginary) {
        this->real = real;
        this->imaginary = imaginary;
    }
};

int main() {

    /*
     * Variables for the real- and imaginary-parts of
     * two complex numbers
     */
    double realA;
    double imaginaryA;
    double realB;
    double imaginaryB;

    /*
     * User input
     */
    cout << "enter real(A), imag(A), real(B) and imag(B) >> ";
    cin >> realA >> imaginaryA >> realB >> imaginaryB;
    cout << endl;

    /*
     * Creation of two objects of the type "ComplexNumber"
     */
    ComplexNumber a = ComplexNumber(realA, imaginaryA);
    ComplexNumber b = ComplexNumber(realB, imaginaryB);

    /*
     * Calling the functions to add, subtract, multiply and 
     * divide the two complex numbers.
     */
    a.add(a, b);
    a.sub(a, b);
    a.multiply(a, b);
    a.divide(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to improve the code.

---

You can find my follow-up question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/236578/).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

- In short programs it can be OK, but in general avoid  writing `using namespace std`. You'll find plenty of material here and elsewhere on why this is so.
- To promote proper [encapsulation of data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)), both `real` and `imaginary` should be declared under `private`, i.e., not be visible to the outside.
- All of the four member functions that perform arithmetic take on too much responsibility and as a result, are very inconvenient for the user. That is, remember: *one function, one responsibility*. If you add, then you don't *also* print. For example, as a user, I just want to use your class for complex arithmetic - I don't want to print every time I do so!
- Your four member functions don't modify the state of the object. This makes the whole class and its functionality quite rigid and strange. As it is, the functionality appears as it should be a collection of four free functions not inside any class (indeed, perhaps your background is in Java where I can imagine this is more common). A more intuitive interface for let's say the addition would be `void add(const ComplexNumber& other) { ... }`, where the implementation actually adds to `real` and `imaginary` of `*this`. Same for the other three operations.
- If you wanted to get fancy, you could use operator overloading to allow for a natural way to express complex arithmetic for the user.
- It would be useful to add a `void print() const { ... }` method in case the user wants to print.
- Use an initializer list if you need to write explicit constructors, i.e., write `ComplexNumber(double r, double i) : real(r), imaginary(i) { }` instead. If you don't, the compiler will call default constructors on the members first which in your case is unnecessary.
- In modern C++, we have the option of using in-class constructors for default values. This is quite handy, i.e., you could have `double real {0.0};` (similarly for `imaginary`) if you wanted to support the creation of complex numbers without an explicit constructor call.
- By the way, you don't have to write `ComplexNumber a = ComplexNumber(realA, imaginaryA);` when it's much cleaner to write `ComplexNumber a(realA, imaginaryA);`.
- Perhaps you know this, but [`std::complex<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) does exist if you wanted to do complex arithmetic in a more serious setting.

Comment: I don't really understand the fourth point. What do you exactly mean?

Comment: @chrysaetos99 it should either be `add(a, b)` returning `c` and not modifying `a` or `b`, or `a.add(b)`, in which `a` gets modified, but not `a.add(a,b)` which is distinctly awkward (after all, `a` is `this`, why is it being passed in as a parameter again?).

Comment: I disagree with the first point.  `using namespace std;` should be avoided in _all_ programs.

Comment: arguably, there's no need to declare these two fields as private because all possible states are valid for this class.

Comment: Operator overloading for arithmetic classes is not fancy and should be the standard way to implement the functionality.

Answer (score 8):

First, note that the complex class is unnecessary because we have [`std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) in the standard library, which is provided in the header [`<complex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/complex).  If you want to design your own class, `std::complex` is a good reference.  Now, for two complex numbers `x` and `y`, we can use `x + y`, `x - y`, `x * y`, and `x / y` directly.

Next, notice that this pattern comes up a few times, with slight modifications:

> ```
> cout << "a + b = " << c.real << " + (" << c.imaginary << ") * i" << endl;
> ```

The outputting of the complex number can be extracted into a function to reduce repetition: (`std::string` requires [`<string>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) and `std::ostringstream` requires [`<sstream>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/sstream))

```
std::string format(std::complex<double> z)
{
    std::ostringstream oss{};
    oss << z.real() << " + (" << z.imag() << ") * i";
    return oss.str();
}
```

Similarly, we can use a separate function to read the real and imaginary parts of a complex number:

```
std::complex<double> read_complex()
{
    double real, imag;
    std::cin >> real >> imag;
    return {real, imag};
}
```

By the way, don't use [`std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/9716597) unless you need the flushing semantics (which usually slows down the program).  Simply use `'\n'` instead.

Putting everything together:

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

std::string format(std::complex<double> z)
{
    std::ostringstream oss{};
    oss << z.real() << " + (" << z.imag() << ") * i";
    return oss.str();
}

std::complex<double> read_complex()
{
    double real, imag;
    std::cin >> real >> imag;
    return {real, imag};
}

int main()
{
    auto x = read_complex();
    auto y = read_complex();

    std::cout << "x + y = " << format(x + y) << '\n';
    std::cout << "x - y = " << format(x - y) << '\n';
    std::cout << "x * y = " << format(x * y) << '\n';
    std::cout << "x / y = " << format(x / y) << '\n';
}
```

([live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wVj7KaXVDx1TbH2L))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't really want to use std::complex, because I wanted to learn to work with complex numbers by myself.

Comment: @chrysaetos99 Remember to add essential info like this in your future questions. Anyway, my point is that your complex class should mimic the (more natural) interface of `std::complex` as explained in other answers.

Comment: `note that the complex class is unnecessary because we have std::complex` I strongly disagree here. While the STL provides many useful constructs, there are often strong arguments why implementing your own version is beneficial.

Comment: Can you cite more than one, @infinitezero? The only reason I can think of to reinvent STL functionality is for educational purposes.

Comment: Speed. STL functions often have a very general purpose. Or missing support, if you you need additional functionality that is not provided by the STL implementation.

Comment: @infinitezero Many implementations of STL are optimized with compiler intrinsics or platform specific assembly tricks IIRC. Besides, the implementers of the standard library are experts compared to the average programmer. And using existing libraries significantly decreases the burden of documenting and testing, and saves development time. “Missing support” is not an issue because you are not reinventing the STL in that case — of course it doesn’t make sense to use a library for features it doesn’t provide right? ;)

Comment: iirc sfml uses a custom complex number class instead of the stl implementation but I couldn't find the link where the maintainer discussed it

Comment: Your `format` function could more naturally be replaced with an overload of `std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, std::complex const&)`. This removes the redundant `std::ostringstream` code.

Comment: @Clearer I thought about that a bit, but since `complex` is a standard type that already has a `operator<<` overload that can normally be picked up by ADL, I regarded adding my own overload in the global namespace to hide the standard one as obfuscating the code semantics a little bit (I would expect `std::cout << std::complex(4, 2)` to print `(4,2)` instead of some user-defined variant). So I provided a separate function instead

Answer (score 7):

Building off the the already excellent points made by Juho,

## Redundant arguments

Within your member function, you never make reference to the object being called on. Take for instance your `ComplexNumber::add` function. A more sound object-oriented implementation might resemble

```
        void add(ComplexNumber other) {

            //Just add real- and imaginary-parts
            double real = this->real + other.real;
            double imaginary = this->imaginary + other.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            cout << "a + b = " << c.real << " + (" << c.imaginary << ") * i" << endl; 
        }
```

## No Returns

The addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division operation you implemented aren't terribly useful to the user since they have no way to access the result. Consider updating all of these member function to return a new complex number, which might look like:

```
        ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber other) {

            //Just add real- and imaginary-parts
            double real = this->real + other.real;
            double imaginary = this->imaginary + other.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            cout << "a + b = " << c.real << " + (" << c.imaginary << ") * i" << endl; 
            return c;
        }
```

Now the can perform operations such as `ComplexNumber sum = a.add(b)`.

## Printing within functions

Write to stdout from inside of a function is usually considered bad practice. If, for instance, I wanted to use your complex number library to write my own CLI application, I would have not way prevent every complex number addition from being printed out. This is rather undesirable. I would recommend moving all of your statements with `cout` to your `main` function, leaving your member functions to resemble

```
        ComplexNumber add(ComplexNumber other) {

            //Just add real- and imaginary-parts
            double real = this->real + other.real;
            double imaginary = this->imaginary + other.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            return c;
        }
```

## Operator Overloading

This is a more advanced C++ concept, but it is good to be aware of. Instead of writing

```
ComplexNumber sum = a.add(b);
```

you can instead have the interface

```
ComplexNumber sum = a + b;
```

by overloading the addition operator for your class. A tutorial describing how to accomplish this can be found [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/92-overloading-the-arithmetic-operators-using-friend-functions/). A possible implementation might look like

````
        ComplexNumber operator+(ComplexNumber other) {

            //Just add real- and imaginary-parts
            double real = this->real + other.real;
            double imaginary = this->imaginary + other.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            return c;
        }
```
````

Comment: Note that if you don't modify the instance you really shouldn't call the method `add`, since that implies modification to most people. That mistake has been made multiple times (hello Java BigInteger) and it always confuses people. So a better name for the second method might be something like `plus` (or just go with the operator overloading and avoid the confusion alltogether)

Comment: Operators are nothing more than functions with a funky name. It's no more advanced than regular functions.