# C++ Calculator for complex numbers - follow-up

Tags: c++, beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, complex-numbers

After following the suggestions from the first question on that topic ([link](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/236550/c-calculator-for-complex-numbers)), I'd like to show you the result now:

```
#include <iostream>

class ComplexNumber {

    private:
        double real;
        double imaginary;

    public:
        ComplexNumber operator+(ComplexNumber b) {

            //Just add real- and imaginary-parts
            double real = this->real + b.real;
            double imaginary = this->imaginary + b.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            return c;
        }

        ComplexNumber operator-(ComplexNumber b) {

            //Just subtract real- and imaginary-parts
            double real = this->real - b.real;
            double imaginary = this->imaginary - b.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            return c;
        }

        ComplexNumber operator*(ComplexNumber b) {

            //Use binomial theorem to find formula to multiply complex numbers
            double real = this->real * b.real - this->imaginary * b.imaginary;
            double imaginary = this->imaginary * b.real + this->real * b.imaginary;
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            return c;
        }


        ComplexNumber operator/(ComplexNumber b) {

            //Again binomial theorem
            double real = (this->real * b.real + this->imaginary * b.imaginary) / (b.real * b.real + b.imaginary * b.imaginary);
            double imaginary = (this->imaginary * b.real - this->real * b.imaginary) / (b.real * b.real + b.imaginary * b.imaginary);
            ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
            return c;
        }

        void printNumber(char mathOperator) {
            std::cout << "a " << mathOperator << " b = " << this->real << " + (" << this->imaginary << ") * i" << std::endl; 
        }

    /*
     * Constructor to create complex numbers
     */
    ComplexNumber(double real = 0.0, double imaginary = 0.0) {
        this->real = real;
        this->imaginary = imaginary;
    }
};

int main() {

    /*
     * Variables for the real- and imaginary-parts of
     * two complex numbers
     */
    double realA;
    double imaginaryA;
    double realB;
    double imaginaryB;

    /*
     * User input
     */
    std::cout << "enter real(A), imag(A), real(B) and imag(B) >> ";
    std::cin >> realA >> imaginaryA >> realB >> imaginaryB;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    /*
     * Creation of two objects of the type "ComplexNumber"
     */
    ComplexNumber a(realA, imaginaryA);
    ComplexNumber b(realB, imaginaryB);

    /*
     * Calling the functions to add, subtract, multiply and 
     * divide the two complex numbers.
     */
    ComplexNumber c = a + b;
    c.printNumber('+');

    c = a - b;
    c.printNumber('-');

    c = a * b;
    c.printNumber('*');

    c = a / b;
    c.printNumber('/');

    return 0;
}
```

If you have any suggestions on further improving the code, I would really appreciate it if you share them with me.

Comment: Stop using the `this->` notation.  It is only necessary to distinguish between member names and method parameters.  Reduce the amount of typing effort and possible typos.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews probably a habit coming from Java. personally I like it because I think it is clearer.

Comment: I've never programmed in Java, but I use `this->` extensively in C++ to refer to member fields, so it's not just a Java-acquired habit. I also think it adds clarity. The alternative for me would be some sort of prefix, like `m_`, which a lot of people think is even uglier. Overall, if having `this->` makes your code hard to read, then there are more fundamental problems, just like if having `std::` makes your code hard to read.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Use field initialization lists:

So your constructor

```
ComplexNumber(double real = 0.0, double imaginary = 0.0) {
    this->real = real;
    this->imaginary = imaginary;
}
```

Can become:

```
ComplexNumber(double real = 0.0, double imaginary = 0.0)
    : real(real), imaginary(imaginary) { }
```

### Simplify your returns

I could see an argument for making an extra `ComplexNumber` to hold your return value if you need to further modify it or if the name of that variable is explanatory in showing what the return means, but as it stands, your `c` is neither of those.

Simplify

```
ComplexNumber c = ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
return c;
```

To just

```
return ComplexNumber(real, imaginary);
```

### Make your operator functions `const`

Since you (correctly) don't modify `a` when you do `a + b`, the operator function can (and should) be declared `const`. That way, even if you have a `const` object, you'll still be able to call it (and if you accidentally try to modify the member variable, you'll know immediately in the form of a compilation error).

That'd look like:

```
ComplexNumber operator+(const ComplexNumber &b) const {
```

Notice I've also declared `b` as `const` here since you shouldn't be modifying it either. I've also passed it by reference to save you some overhead.

### Make your class printable with `std::cout`

Your `printNumber` is very specific. In fact, if you ever want to use this class for anything other than simply showing arithmetic results, that print may not be what you want. Instead, I'd make a generic `str()` that just returns a string version of the complex number. Something like:

```
std::string str() {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << this->real << " + (" << this->imaginary << ") * i";
    return oss.str(); 
}
```

And then in the global scope, you can overload the `<<` operator for `std::cout`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, const ComplexNumber &cn) {
    return os << cn.str();
}
```

And now when you want to print it in `main()`, you can say:

```
std::cout << "a + b = " << a + b << std::endl;
std::cout << "a - b = " << a - b << std::endl;
std::cout << "a * b = " << a * b << std::endl;
std::cout << "a / b = " << a / b << std::endl;
```

Look at how easy that becomes to read and understand!

Comment: Terminology - it's not a *syntax* error to attempt to write a read-only value.  Syntax refers to *parsing* the program text.  That's just a nit-pick; great review otherwise!

Comment: @Toby perhaps I have it wrong, but I believe in C++ trying to modify a read-only (or `const`) variable will result in a syntax error as a result of the language being strongly typed (and so this being something the compiler can parse and catch), no?

Comment: Hmm I think we may be saying the same thing here @Toby. Trying to modify a `const` variable is likely the result of a semantic error, but it'll be caught at compile time and shown as a syntax error by the compiler, which lines up with: "*and if you accidentally try to modify the member variable, you'll know immediately in the form of a syntax error*" right? Is there some way you think I should edit that line to make it more correct with what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, it's a compilation error.  No, it's not an error of *syntax*.  That's the minor distinction I'm making.  In English, "My car blue is" is a syntax error, and "My car smells blue" is not a syntax error, but it's still broken.  See [syntax versus sematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_(programming_languages)#Syntax_versus_semantics)

Comment: Ahh I think I see @Toby. I guess I've had it in my head that a compilation error is always a syntax error. But it looks like it's more of a rectangle/square situation.

Comment: The lines are further blurred in C++, too, since whether something is syntactically correct can depend on the semantics of the expression. Parsing C++ is hard!

Comment: I'd switch the the ``str()`` and ``std::ostream& operator<<`` logic around. Stream it into the ``ostream`` how you want it formatted. And in the ``str()`` method you just stream ``*this`` into the ``stringstream`` and catch the string. Saves the overhead of creating a string object every time you stream the object.

Comment: @Brain I've seen both ways. Personally I prefer this since it doesn't require friending a function (which I consider bad practice when it's avoidable).

Comment: @scohe001 avoiding unneeded dynamic allocations is arguably more important than avoiding a friended function (especially the most used one there is and one that would be a member function if possible). I’d go as far as saying that friending that operator is essentially unavoidable. Because avoiding it with way worse coding practices is waaaay worse.

Answer (score 7):

## Member Access

In the real world, people often care about being able to look at the real and imaginary parts of a complex number individually. As such, you will want to provide an interface to them. While contrary to some of the advice you revived in your last review, I'd advise giving these members variables `public` access. These components are not an implementation detail of your class. Being able to freely read and mutate the components of a complex number is simply part of the expected interface.

## Coupling with `main` and `std::cout`

In your current implementation, `ComplexNumber` includes a public function `printNumber` to display the complex number as an expression of `a` and `b`. However, `a` and `b` have no meaning within the class itself, and only exist in your `main` function. Likewise,  `printNumber` always prints the complex number to  `std::cout`. Out in the wild, developers may want to write a complex number to other places, such as  `std::cerr` or a file.

Right now, this functionality isn't as useful as it could be for an outside user. What would be more helpful is the ability to print a complex number itself to *any* output stream.

The most robust way to accomplish this would be by [overloading the I/O operators](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/). A possible implemetation might look like

```
class ComplexNumber {
    // ... snip
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, ComplexNumber c);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, ComplexNumber c) {
    out << c.real << " + " << c.imaginary << 'i';
    return out;
}
```

Using this implementation, you can print `ComplexNumber` instances directly to `std::cout` via

```
ComplexNumber c(2, 3);    
std::cout << c;  // prints 2 + 3i
```

Comment: While I mostly agree with you on "Member Access", it's interesting to note that `std::complex` does not.

Comment: Hello, I've tried to understand the syntax for a couple of days now, but I don't really get it. Could you maybe explain the "friend"-syntax you are using to me?

Comment: @chrysaetos99 See the explanation given on [this website](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/813-friend-functions-and-classes/). Using `friend` functions is a common idiom to allow overloaded operators to access the private state of a class without being member functions themselves.

Answer (score 5):

As in your previous question, your interface is still awkward. That is, if there's an `add` method, I fully expect that calling `a.add(b)` will mean that a results in a plus b. So in particular, the state of `a` will be changed.

A user of your class will also find `void printNumber(char mathOperator)` weird. Indeed, why as a user of the class do I need to worry about such details meaning the parameter? The user will just want to get his/her complex number printed and not be forced to worry about such details. So such a function might make sense as a private workhorse (but do make it `const` and read more about `const` - it's good for you) that `operator<<` can call, as explained in another answer.

Answer (score 5):

## Operator Consistency

You provide operators for `+`, `-`, etc., but as it is some things I would expect to do are illegal, such as

```cpp
ComplexNumber c(1, 2);
ComplexNumber d(3, 4);
d += c;
```

Generally the recommendation with these forms of operators is to implement the `+=` form in your class, and then define `+` as a non-member in terms of `+=`. For example:

```
class ComplexNumber {
public:
  // ...
  ComplexNumber& operator+=(ComplexNumber b) {
    this->real += b.real;
    this->imaginary += b.imaginary;
    return *this;
  }

  friend ComplexNumber operator+(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {
    // note a is a copy here
    a += b;
    return a;
  }

  // and so forth for -, *, /
};
```

Doing it this way also means that

```
ComplexNumber c(1, 2);
ComplexNumber d = c + 1;  // compiles with both your code and mine
ComplexNumber e = 1 + c;  // only compiles with the above changes
```

will compile. If it's not desirable that a number `1` will implicitly convert to a `ComplexNumber`, consider marking your constructor `explicit`.

Answer (score 4):

People have talked about simplifying the return temporary, but not the interior temporaries:

```
ComplexNumber operator+(ComplexNumber a, ComplexNumber b) {
    //Just add real- and imaginary-parts
    return ComplexNumber(a.real + b.real,
                         a.imaginary + b.imaginary);
}
```

Conversely, sometimes you should make a temporary.  Notably, the denominator in the a/b calculation should be a temporary.
Mind you, this is the absolute value of b, so maybe that line reads (given the relevant function is defined):

```
double abs_b = abs(b);
```